# Supporting Multiple transformers to RequestBody in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller that takes a RequestBody as a post:

```
public void postIt(@RequestBody Foo foo) {}
```

I have a new version of the API where `Foo` has been replaced with `Bar`. I still need to support people posting `Foo` but they should be able to post `Bar` for new customers. `Foo` and Bar have the same information, `Bar` is just easier to use.

So rather than having two controller methods I would like to be able to tell Spring "If someone posts `Foo` to this endpoint, transform it to `Bar`" by giving it a mapper function.

Note that this is different / after String parsing (we support both JSON with Jackson AND XML with JaxB)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to have two methods?

Comment: I have to actually change the path. Spring doesn't seem to be able to differentiate between two different RequestBodies. Honestly I've tried this several ways I don't think I can do this and have auto binding to types. It seems like I would need to just take the body as a string and do it myself (maybe as a aspect or interceptor)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an before Aspect for this method and do the conversion there.